# php calculate file size after reading the content

Tags: php

Using php i have contents of a file through file_get_contents() function. I want to calculate the size of the file using the contents. Is there a precise way to do it ?

I tried strlen(contents) , suggested in one of the answers , but there is quite difference in size returned and actual file size on computer.

Note : using ubuntu 12.04

**EDIT** : sorry for the waste of time guys, it seems the contents were base64_encode() which led to mismatch in sizes. I appreciate your time and effort. Sorry again.

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference in size? `strlen` produces the amount of characters (bytes) in the contents. Multiply that by 1024 to get the correct amount of kb. And so forth. From PHP.net: `strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.`

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the size of the file or the amount of characters in the file?

Comment: what about using php function http://php.net/filesize ?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of such a "quite difference"?

Comment: @deceze , file size on my system 1536420 bytes , size returned by strlen 2048560

Comment: How *exactly* are you getting the number 1536420?

Comment: by viewing properties of the file , size value

Comment: this might help you.. http://kr1.php.net/strlen#45407  also make sure that you haven't used any trim or equivalent functions on your string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if *strlen()* doesn't return the length in bytes, check that 'function overloading' of mbstring is not enabled : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Comment: function overloading of mbstring is not enabled and strlen() does return the size in bytes

Answer (score 1):

Check [filesize()](http://php.net/filesize) for that and try like this

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
echo $filename . ': ' . filesize($filename) . ' bytes';
```

Comment: I dont have the file location , only contents :(